# Error when running my C++ Pthread Program - Segmentation Fault (Core Dump)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am c++ beginner currently writing a `pthread` program and when I compile the program, it does not shows any error message. However, when I run the program, I get the `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error message on my ubuntu machine.

Below are my c++ codes and the header file.

mazesolver.cpp

```
#include "mazesolver.h"

int main()
{
// Elapsed Time
time(&startTime);

// Start Process
if (start() == EXIT_FAILURE)
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Create Threads
if (create() == EXIT_FAILURE)
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Explore the Map
explore();

// End the Process
if (end() == EXIT_FAILURE)
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Return Success
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int start()
{
string tempData;

// Create File if not Found
fstream file(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

// If file not found create new file
if (!file)
{
    fstream createFile(fileName.c_str(), ios::out);
    createFile.close();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// If file contents are empty
else if(file.peek() == file.eof())
{
    cout << "-- File Contains No Data --\n\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Allocate memory
AllocateProgramsVariableMemory();

// Load the Maze Obj
mazeObj->LoadMaze(fileName);

// Create new instance of the maze
Maze * mazeSoln = new Assignm3::Maze(mazeObj->getLength(), mazeObj->getBreadth(), mazeObj->getStartLocation(), mazeObj->getEndLocation());

// Discovered Solution Path
discoveredASolutionPath = false;

// Get necesssary data from global finder resource
// for maze and initialize as 0 as it is the
// start of the process
globalPathFinderResource.usedThreadNameIndex = 0;
globalPathFinderResource.noOfDeadEndPathsFound = 0;
globalPathFinderResource.noOfBarriersDiscovered = 0;
globalPathFinderResource.noOfDangerAreaDiscovered = 0;

// Initialize neessary data to 0
activeThreads = 0;
submittedPaths = 0;
numSoln = 0;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int create()
{
while (discoveredASolutionPath == false)
{
    if (areThreadsActive[2] == false && activeThreads > 0)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&globalPathFinderResource.activeThreadArray[2], NULL, display, NULL) != 0)
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        else
        {
            areThreadsActive[2] = true;
        }
    }

    if (activeThreads < (MAX_NO_OF_THREADS-1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (MAX_NO_OF_THREADS-1); i++)
        {
            if (areThreadsActive[i] == false)
            {
                PathFinderParameterInfo threadData;
                threadData.threadName = THREAD_NAMES[globalPathFinderResource.usedThreadNameIndex % 63];
                threadData.threadIDArrayIndex = i;

                globalPathFinderResource.activeThreadParamArray[i] = &threadData;

                if (pthread_create(&globalPathFinderResource.activeThreadArray[i], NULL, findPath, (void *) &threadData) != 0)
                {
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

                else
                {
                    areThreadsActive[i] = true;
                    globalPathFinderResource.usedThreadNameIndex++;

                    activeThreads++;

                    // Block Out
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

                    cout << "Thread '" << threadData.threadName << "' has been created!\n\n";

                    // Unlock
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void explore()
{
// Suspend execution for 4 seconds
usleep(4000000);

// Block Out
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

cout << "Finished Finding a SAFE PATH!\n";
cout << "Printing Submitted maze solution:\n\n";

// Print and save accordingly
submitMazeSolnObj->printSubmittedSolution(studentName, studentID);
submitMazeSolnObj->saveSubmittedSolution(studentName, studentID);

statistics();

// Unlock
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
}

int end()
{
// If there are any threads still active
// return a failure
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO_OF_THREADS; i++)
{
    if (pthread_join(globalPathFinderResource.activeThreadArray[i], NULL) != 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

DeallocateProgramsVariableMemory();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void * findPath(void * tempData)
{
PathFinderParameterInfo threadData = *((PathFinderParameterInfo *) tempData);

// Get the location of map
Point startLocation = mazeObj->getStartLocation();
Point endLocation = mazeObj->getEndLocation();

// Assign start location
threadData.currentLocation = startLocation;

// 
VectorOfPointStructType taken;
VectorOfPointStructType checked;

// Put into data
taken.push_back(threadData.currentLocation);

do
{
    if (discoveredASolutionPath)
    {
        areThreadsActive[threadData.threadIDArrayIndex] = false;
        activeThreads--;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    Point up(threadData.currentLocation.x, threadData.currentLocation.y + 1);
    Point down(threadData.currentLocation.x, threadData.currentLocation.y+ - 1);
    Point left(threadData.currentLocation.x - 1, threadData.currentLocation.y);
    Point right(threadData.currentLocation.x + 1, threadData.currentLocation.y);

    srand(time(NULL));

    string random = "0123";

    // Randomize the 4 actions
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int x = (rand () % random.size());
        char y = random[x];

        random.erase(remove(random.begin(), random.end(), y), random.end());

        int temp;

        if (threadData.threadIDArrayIndex == 0)
        {
            temp = i;
        }

        else
        {
            temp = y - '0';
        }

        // Do actions
        switch(temp)
        {
            case 0: 
                checked.push_back(up);
                break;

            case 1: 
                checked.push_back(down);
                break;

            case 2: 
                checked.push_back(left);
                break;

            case 3: 
                checked.push_back(right);
                break;
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(up) || mazeSolution->IsThereDanger(up))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(down) || mazeSolution->IsThereDanger(down))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(left) || mazeSolution->IsThereDanger(left))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(right) || mazeSolution->IsThereDanger(right))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    if (counter == 3)
    {
        // Block Out
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

        // Show where did it hit a dead end
        cout << "Thread '" << threadData.threadName << "' hits a Dead End near ";
        threadData.currentLocation.display(cout);
        cout << ".\n";

        globalPathFinderResource.noOfDeadEndPathsFound++;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
    }

    int backtrack = checked.size() + 1;

    threadData.currentLocation = checked[backtrack];
    checked.pop_back();

    int counter2 = 0;

    while (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(threadData.currentLocation) || pathObj->isLocationInPath(threadData.currentLocation, taken) || mazeSolution->IsThereDanger(threadData.currentLocation) || hitBoundary(threadData.currentLocation))
    {
        if (checked.size() < 1)
        {
            areThreadsActive[threadData.threadIDArrayIndex] = false;
            activeThreads--;
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }

        if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(threadData.currentLocation))
        {
            // Block Out
            pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

            addBarrier(threadData.currentLocation, taken);

            // Unlock
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
        }

        // Return the last location
        threadData.currentLocation = checked.back();
        checked.push_back(threadData.currentLocation);
        counter2++;
    }

    if (mazeObj->IsThereDanger(threadData.currentLocation))
    {
        // Block Out
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

        cout << "Thread '" << threadData.threadName << "' stepped into Danger at ";
        threadData.currentLocation.display(cout);
        cout << ".\n";

        addDanger(threadData.currentLocation, taken);

        areThreadsActive[threadData.threadIDArrayIndex] = false;

        activeThreads--;

        cout << "Thread '" << threadData.threadName << "is dead. His sacrifice will not be made in vain!\n";

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    if (counter2 > 3)
    {
        // Return the last point
        Point tempP = taken.back();

        while (!tempP.isConnected(threadData.currentLocation))
        {
            taken.pop_back();
            tempP = taken.back();
        }

        taken.push_back(threadData.currentLocation);
    }

    if (counter2 < 4)
    {
        taken.push_back(threadData.currentLocation);
    }

    if (threadData.currentLocation == endLocation)
    {
        if (!discoveredASolutionPath)
        {
            cout << "Thread '" << threadData.threadName << "' found a solution! Well done!\n";

            // Block Out
            pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

            addSolution(threadData.currentLocation, taken);

            // Unlock
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);

            areThreadsActive[threadData.threadIDArrayIndex] = false;
            activeThreads--;

            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
} while (!discoveredASolutionPath);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

bool hitBoundary(Point tempCurrLoc)
{
if ((tempCurrLoc.x < 0) || (tempCurrLoc.x >= mazeObj->getLength()))
{
    return true;
}

else if ((tempCurrLoc.y < 0) || (tempCurrLoc.y >= mazeObj->getBreadth()))
{
    return true;
}

return false;
}

void addDanger(Point tempCurrLoc, VectorOfPointStructType tempTaken)
{
globalPathFinderResource.noOfDangerAreaDiscovered++;
globalPathFinderResource.discoveredDangerAreas.push_back(tempCurrLoc);

submittedPaths++;

taken.push_back(tempCurrLoc);
submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToDangerArea(pthread_self(), taken);

mazeSolution->updateMaze(tempCurrLoc, DANGER_INT);
}

void addSolution(Point tempCurrLoc, VectorOfPointStructType tempTaken)
{
globalPathFinderResource.solutionPath = taken;
numSoln++;
submittedPaths++;

allPaths.push_back(taken);

submitMazeSolnObj->submitSolutionPath(pthread_self(), taken);

mazeSolution->AddNewPath(taken);

if (numSoln == maxNoOfSolutions)
{
    discoveredASolutionPath = true;
}
}

void addBarrier(Point tempCurrLoc, VectorOfPointStructType tempTaken)
{
if (find(barriers.begin(), barriers.end(), tempCurrLoc) == barriers.end())
{
    barriers.push_back(tempCurrLoc);
    globalPathFinderResource.noOfBarriersDiscovered++;
}

submittedPaths++;

tempTaken.push_back(tempCurrLoc);
submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToBarrier(pthread_self(), taken);

mazeSolution->updateMaze(tempCurrLoc, BARRIER_INT);
}

void * display(void * empty)
{
// Block Out
pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);

// Suspend execution for 4 seconds
usleep(4000000);
time(&endTime);

cout << "=======================================================\n";
cout << "Elasped Time: " << difftime(endTime, startTime) << "\n";
cout << "Latest Update: \n";
cout << "=======================================================\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "Dead End Paths Found  : " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfDeadEndPathsFound << "\n";
cout << "Barriers Discovered   : " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfBarriersDiscovered << "\n";
cout << "Danger Area Discovered: " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfDangerAreaDiscovered << "\n";
cout << "\n";

areThreadsActive[2] = false;

// Unlock
pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void statistics()
{
// Create an output buffer to store
streambuf * buffer;
ostream output(buffer);

// Capture all display
output << "Information:\n";
output << "Threads Active     : " << globalPathFinderResource.usedThreadNameIndex << "\n";
output << "Paths Submitted    : " << submittedPaths << "\n";
output << "Solutions Submitted: " << numSoln << "\n";
output << "\n";

output << "Discoveries:\n";
output << "Dead Ends Found   : " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfDeadEndPathsFound << "\n";
output << "Barriers Found    : " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfBarriersDiscovered << "\n";
output << "Danger Areas Found: " << globalPathFinderResource.noOfDangerAreaDiscovered << "\n";
output << "\n";

// Get the shortest path
VectorOfPointStructType final = getShortestPath();

output << "Shortest Path Found: ";

final.pop_back();
mazeObj->ShowPathGraphically(final, output);
}

VectorOfPointStructType getShortestPath()
{
int min = 0;
for(int i=1; i < allPaths.size(); i++)
{
    if(allPaths[i].size() < allPaths[min].size())
        min = i;
}

return allPaths[min];
}
```

mazesolver.h

```
#ifndef MAZESOLVER_H
#define MAZESOLVER_H

#include <pthread.h>

#include "Path.h"
#include "Maze.h"
#include "SubmitMazeSoln.h"
#include "Assignm3_Utils.h"
#include "Assignm3.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <streambuf>

using namespace std;
using namespace Assignm3;

const string fileName = "mazedata.txt";
const string studentName = "Foo Ce Zhong";
const string studentID = "5363391";

Maze * mazeSolution;
VectorOfPointStructType barriers;
VectorOfVectorOfPointStructType allPaths;

time_t startTime, endTime;

bool areThreadsActive[MAX_NO_OF_THREADS];
VectorOfPointStructType taken;
VectorOfPointStructType checked;

int activeThreads;
int submittedPaths;
int numSoln;
int maxNoOfSolutions;

int start();    // start the process
int create();   // create threads
void explore(); // display paths
int end();  // end the process
void *findPath(void *);
void *display(void *);
bool hitBoundary(Point);
void addBarrier(Point, VectorOfPointStructType);
void addDanger(Point, VectorOfPointStructType);
void addSolution(Point, VectorOfPointStructType);
void statistics();
VectorOfPointStructType getShortestPath();

#endif
```

Output of my executable

```
 vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Master$ ./mazesolver.exe 

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  0  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
  1  #  S     #        #                                      #
  2  #        #     #  #        #  #        #  #  #     #  #  #
  3  #                 #           #           #        E     #
  4  #  #     #        #     X     #        X        #  #     #
  5  #           X     #  #  #     #  #  #  #  #              #
  6  #     #           #           #        #           #  #  #
  7  #     #  #  #     #  #  #     #  #     #     #  #  #  #  #
  8  #        #                                               #
  9  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #

_length  : 20
_breadth : 10

_startLocation : [ 1, 1 ]
_endLocation   : [ 17, 3 ]

No. of paths discovered : 0

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  0                                                            
  1     S                                                      
  2                                                            
  3                                                     E      
  4                                                            
  5                                                            
  6                                                            
  7                                                            
  8                                                            
  9                                                            

_length  : 20
_breadth : 10

_startLocation : [ 1, 1 ]
_endLocation   : [ 17, 3 ]

No. of paths discovered : 0

Thread 'POOH' has been created!

Thread 'TIGGER' has been created!

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Sorry for the spam but I guess its better for you guys to have the full picture.Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: Run it through the debugger and obtain a backtrace, to know which function and line are the culprit.

Comment: the findPath function is the one giving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Debugging a multi threaded program needs care full debugging and understanding of the code. First step would be to find the function that is causing the memory exception.  You can get the stack trace using gdb.

```
Run "gdb <exe name> <core file>"
On the gdb prompt type "where" to get the stack trace.
```

Other option would be to run the executable using the debugger

I have also noticed your code uses lower case function names like "create",
"start" etc. It is not recommended to use because many OS system calls similar
names and sometimes clash with the user defined functions and hard to debug
if a program is built using libraries from multiple vendors.

Comment: findPath function is the one giving the problem